# How to fetch all pending notifications from iCloud and notify it that my app received notification?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Usually I receive notifications immediately when record changes.

But what to do when my app is not running, and I need to fetch all pending notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do it like this:

```
func fetchPendingNotifications() {

    var queryNotifications = [CKQueryNotification]()

    let operation = CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: nil)
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

    operation.notificationChangedBlock = { notification in

        if let queryNotification = notification as? CKQueryNotification {
            queryNotifications.append(queryNotification)
        }
    }

    operation.fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock = { _, error in

        if error == nil {

            self.perform(queryNotifications: queryNotifications) { _ in

                //do sth on success
            }
        }
    }

    operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
}
```

the helper function is:

```
private func perform(queryNotifications: [CKQueryNotification], completion: ErrorHandler? = nil) {

    var currentQueryNotifications = queryNotifications

    if let queryNotification = currentQueryNotifications.first {

        currentQueryNotifications.removeFirst()

        if queryNotification.queryNotificationReason == .recordCreated || queryNotification.queryNotificationReason == .recordUpdated {

            //fetch the record from cloud and save to core data
            self.fetchAndSave(with: queryNotification.recordID!) { error in 

                if error == nil {

                    OperationQueue().addOperation(CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation(notificationIDsToMarkRead: [queryNotification.notificationID!]))
                    self.perform(queryNotifications: currentQueryNotifications, completion: completion)

                } else {
                    completion?(error)
                }
            }

        } else {
            //delete record from coredata
            self.delete(with: queryNotification.recordID!) { error in

                if error == nil {

                    OperationQueue().addOperation(CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation(notificationIDsToMarkRead: [queryNotification.notificationID!]))
                    self.perform(queryNotifications: currentQueryNotifications, completion: completion)

                } else {
                    completion?(error)
                }
            }
        }

    } else {

        completion?(nil)
    }
}
```